# Yum client configuration: How to use basic authentication with a port other than 80?

Tags: http, authentication, yum

I've run into an issue configuring a Yum repository which I'm serving up with HTTP/Apache.

I want to use http basic authentication, and set the listening port to something other than 80, because this repo is in my DMZ.  I was trying to do that by setting up my baseurl as follows (from my repo file):

```
baseurl=http://user:password@<my-ip>:<my-non-80-port>/yum/RHEL/7/base/$basearch/
```

The documentation for yum.conf indicates you can do basic http authentication by adding the username/password to the URL as I did above.  I get the following error when I try to do a `yum search mysql` from a client:

```
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

This indicated to me that the extra ":" specifying the port was confusing yum's parsing of my url.  I removed the port, set the server back to port 80, and it works.

So it appears you cannot do basic http authentication AND change the port number that the web server listens on.  I noticed that there are `username` and `password` directives in newer version of Yum, but my version doesn't appear to have this directives (I am running yum-3.2.22-37.0.1.el5).  Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by turning off plugins by adding the following line to my yum configuration.

```
plugins=0
```

I think the workaround worked because the base yum updater was working fine with the authorization information from baseurl, but some of the plugins (such as the fastmirror plugin) didn't remember the authorization properly.  So the behaviour I had without plugins enabled is that initially an update would work, then subsequently it would start to fail with the authorization error in the question.  Once I disabled plugins, everything started to work fine.